# How to shorten input value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery and it is getting long.

Is there any way to shorten this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$('input[value|=Kjøp],input[value|=Buy],input[value|=Fortsett å handle],input[value|=Skriv deg inn her],input[value|=Logg inn],input[value|=Lagre],input[value|=Logg deg på],input[value|=Continue shopping],input[value|=Register as a customer],input[value|=Login],input[value|=Gå til kassen],input[value|=Proceed to checkout],input[value|=Save],input[value|=Fullfør bestillingen],input[value|=Confirm the order],input[value|=Neste],input[value|=Next],input[value|=Forrige],input[value|=Back],input[value|=Forsett til betaling],input[value|=Continue to make the payment],input[value|=Send],input[value|=Logg ut],input[value|=Log off],input[value|=Rediger dine kundeopplysninger],input[value|=Edit your information]').addClass("buybtn");
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to add the class dynamically?  It seems as though you know what input fields you need to set at compile time, why not just add the class at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all those `input` elements a common class (manually -- type it in)

```
<input class="chooseMe" value="Kjøp" />


$('input.chooseMe').addClass("buybtn");
```

Comment: Hmm.. might as well just type in the buybtn class manually :)

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the selector dynamically (assuming you have added Array.map)...

```
values = ['Kjøp', 'Buy', 'Fortsett å handle', ...];
sel = values.map(function(x){return 'input[value|='+x+']'}).join(',')
$(sel).addClass("buybtn");
```

Or `.filter` the result,

```
values = {'Kjøp':1, 'Buy':1, 'Fortsett å handle':1, ...};
$('input').filter(function() {
   var val = this.value();
   var minus = val.indexOf('-');
   if (minus >= 0)
     val = val.substr(0, minus);
   return val in values;
}).addClass("buybtn");
```